# Any way to implement a "checkbox group" (like RadioButton group) in android?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I'm developing a quiz-like app in android. Each question is a recycler view item so that I can have multiple question types presented sequentially. My question is: is there any way of implementing a CheckBox group just like the RadioButton group? With the RadioButton group, I'm able to add answers (RadioButton's) by simply calling:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.answer_grp);
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton("context...");
rb.setText("text");
radioGroup.addView(rb);
```

Is there any implementation of a Checkbox group similar to this? Should I use the implementation of the RadioButton group provided and customize the layout of the RadioButton to look like a checkbox? What's the best possible practice in this case?

Thanks very much in advance!

[image: Radio button group I'm using]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this library https://github.com/xeoh/CheckBoxGroup

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! But this still doesn't let me add checkboxes programmatically to the checkbox group right? This helps me deal with multiple existing checkboxes and its values but it does not allow me to create and add checkbox views programmatically?

Comment: you can actually @poider12, see here: https://github.com/xeoh/CheckBoxGroup#more-usage

Comment: or you can use this library instead: https://github.com/jolsondc/CheckBoxExample @Poider12

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout` to group `CheckBox` together, and implement `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` for your class to handle checked change event:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    CheckBox q1A1CheckBox;
    CheckBox q1A2CheckBox;
    CheckBox q1A3CheckBox;
    CheckBox q1A4CheckBox;
    CheckBox q2A1CheckBox;
    CheckBox q2A2CheckBox;
    CheckBox q2A3CheckBox;
    CheckBox q2A4CheckBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        q1A1CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.main_q1_a1_checkBox);
        q1A2CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.main_q1_a2_checkBox);
        q1A3CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.main_q1_a3_checkBox);
        q1A4CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.main_q1_a4_checkBox);
        q2A1CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.main_q2_a1_checkBox);
        q2A2CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.main_q2_a2_checkBox);
        q2A3CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.main_q2_a3_checkBox);
        q2A4CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.main_q2_a4_checkBox);

        q1A1CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        q1A2CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        q1A3CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        q1A4CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        q2A1CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        q2A2CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        q2A3CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        q2A4CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        int currentCheckBoxGroupId = ((LinearLayout) compoundButton.getParent()).getId();

        switch (currentCheckBoxGroupId) {
            case R.id.main_q1_linearLayout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Question one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //do whatever you want

                break;

            case R.id.main_q2_linearLayout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Question two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //do whatever you want

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RadioGroup and RadioButton.
we need to add these two properties to RadioButton

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```